# Function template with explicit specification of type

Tags: c++, function-templates

I'm trying to understand below sample code I have. 
I know we can explicitly specify data type but not sure what "int, double" and "int, int" means.
And why do we write function template that way instead of T tripleit (T Val) { T temp = val * 3; }?
Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
// why do we write this way instead of T tripleit (T Val) { T temp = val * 3; }?
template <class T, class U>
T tripleit (U val)
{
    T temp = val * 3;

}


int main()
{
    int a=5;
    double d=3.3;

    cout << "Explicit int; int argument: " << tripleit<int>(a) << endl;
    cout << "Explicit int; double argument: " << tripleit<int>(d) << endl;

    // what does <int, double> and <int, int> mean?
    cout << "Explicit int, double; double argument: " << tripleit<int, double>(d) << endl;
    cout << "Explicit int, int; double argument: " << tripleit<int, int>(d) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

By the way, the output is :

Explicit int; int argument: 15

Explicit int; double argument: 9

Explicit int, double; double argument: 9

Explicit int, int; double argument: 9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the template parameters had more descriptive names, they could look like this:

```
template <class ReturnType, class ParameterType>
ReturnType tripleit (ParameterType val)
{
  ReturnType temp = val * 3;
  return temp;  // I assume this line is actually present in your code, it makes no sense otherwise
}
```

With these names, it should be a bit more clear. The function can be used to multiply a number by 3 and convert it to a desired type at the same time.

Invoking the template with both template arguments specified simply suppresses template argument deduction. I think the really interesting case is missing there:

```
cout << "Explicit double, int; double argument: " << tripleit<double, int>(d) << '\n';
```

This will pass in a `double` value `3.3`. However, as `ParameterType` is explicitly specified to be `int`, the value will be converted to `int` (perhaps with a warning). Inside the function, `temp` will be of type `double` (the first template argument), but the return value will still be 9, so the expected output is `9` or perhaps `9.0` or `9.0e0` depending on the current `cout` settings for floating-point numbers.

Comment: is it necessary to return the value in templates? Thanks.

Comment: @kbear I don't quite understand your question. Every function with a return type other than `void` must return a value, whether it's a plain function or a template instantiation.

Comment: Yea, you're right. I don't know what I was thinking. Thanks so much for your help.